# NullReferenceException when setting NavigationService source

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, navigationservice

I'm trying to navigate to MainPage.xaml if access_token isn't set.

```
  public Menu()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
                if (((App)App.Current).access_token == null) {
                  NavigationService.Source=new Uri("/MainPage.xaml", UriKind.Relative);//NullReferenceException

                }.../
```

Comment: Presumably `NavigationService` is null. Where is this initialised?

Comment: Could this apply to Windows Phone as well? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2712218/silverlight-navigationservice-is-always-null

Comment: @UrbanEsc The root cause could be the same, there's not much detail from the OP. However I'd be nervous about changing RootFrame in Windows Phone without careful thought. For example: the Silverlight Toolkit uses this technique to support page transition animations, but those guys know what they're doing ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If this is your Main page and you are just starting the application I wouldn't expect that the Silverlight `NavigationService` is initialized at the time when the `MainPage` object is first constructed. I'd guess you're creating Menu in the MainPage constructor, so that would explain the `NullReferenceException`.

You will need to trigger your navigation at a later event in the MainPage. If it were me I'd try the `Loaded` event first, but you may need to experiment to get this behaviour correct...